# Double switch C#

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I see in old code two function that uses same switch like this:

```
private string GetPath(Charts chartType)
{
    switch (chartType)
    {
        case Charts.Revenue:
            return "/../..";
        case Charts.Risk:
            return "/../some";
        //UPDATE
        case Charts.Sales
            return "/123/xxx"
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException($"{chartType} is not implemented yet!");
    }
}

public IStrategy GetStrategy(RequestDto request)
{
    if (!Enum.TryParse<Charts>(request.GraphType, true, out var chartType))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown value for {nameof(RequestDto.GraphType)}", nameof(RequestDto.GraphType));
    }

    var path = GetPath(chartType);

    switch (chartType)
    {
        case Charts.Revenue:
        case Charts.Risk:
            return new BarChartStrategy(path, _component1, _component2);
        //UPDATE
        case Charts.Sales
            return new PieChartStrategy(path, _component1, _component2);
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException($"Charts.{chartType} is not implemented yet!");
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant form, more OOP form for these two switch?
Thanks

UPDATE:
I clirify my scenario.
I can have multiple stretegy for chart, like BarChartStrategy, CircleChartStrategy, TreeChartStrategy.
Revenue and Risk uses BarChartStrategy, but others can use different strategies.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please always post complete and real code, or else we can not make a proper review. Please do not update your original code when an answer is submitted - because that will invalidate the answer(s). You're welcome to make an update below your original code - starting with **UPDATE** that clearly signals that it's new stuff - thanks.

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look a the [help/on-topic].

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, and it has a classic OOP answer:

```
public IStrategy GetStrategy(RequestDto request) =>    
    ChartType.TryParse(request.GraphType, out var chartType) 
    ? chartType.Strategy(_component1, _component2)
    : throw new ArgumentException();
```

Where:

```
public class ChartType
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, ChartType> All = 
        new Dictionary<string, ChartType>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    public static bool TryParse(string text, out ChartType type) =>
        All.TryGetValue(text, out type);

    public static readonly ChartType Revenue = new ChartType(cc => new BarChartStrategy("/../..", cc));
    public static readonly ChartType Risk = new ChartType(cc => new BarChartStrategy("/../some", cc));
    public static readonly ChartType Sales = new ChartType(cc => new PieChartStrategy("/123/xxx", cc));

    ChartType(Func<IComponent[], IStrategy> factory, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        All[name] = this;
        Factory = factory;
    }

    Func<IComponent[], IStrategy> Factory { get; }
    public IStrategy Strategy(params IComponent[] components) =>
        Factory(components);
}
```

Not so many people could read OOP code these days though. It looks like an overkill for the snippet you have, but it scales up very well.

Comment: "Not so many people could read OOP code these days though." In C#?

Comment: OOP in C# is a pretty rarely thing. Some other languages could be a way more efficient, but high-condensity FP usually wins when language and qualification allows. Generally speaking, there is no high demand in precise modeling which only OOP could provide.

Comment: Hi @DmitryNogin, thx very much. This is a real clean Factory pattern in C#. One question. Cai I use Lazy<ChartType> to not instantiate all charts class but only when it is used?

Comment: @GlaucoCucchiar `ChartType` is just a factory (a named one) as well as `Lazy<T>` given what I see here. You probably won't win much by using two levels of nested factories. Message [me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/dnogin/) in case you are interested in sharing some real code which could be different :)

Answer (score 2):

If `GetPath` is used in multiple places, then I believe it would better to leave it as is, otherwise, you'll have to change every method that reference it. If this is the only method that is used in then combine it like this :

```
public IStrategy GetStrategy(RequestDto request)
{
    if (!Enum.TryParse<Charts>(request.GraphType, true, out var chartType))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown value for {nameof(RequestDto.GraphType)}", nameof(RequestDto.GraphType));
    }

    switch (chartType)
    {
        case Charts.Revenue:
            return new BarChartStrategy("/../..", _component1, _component2);
        case Charts.Risk:
            return new BarChartStrategy("/../some", _component1, _component2);
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException($"Charts.{chartType} is not implemented yet!");
    }
}
```

This way you can manage both the path and also the `BarChartStrategy` in the same place. 
and since the path is stored in `BarChartStrategy` property, you can always retrieve it from any active instance. Which eliminate the need of `GetPath` in the first place.